# null pointer exception

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {

List list = new List(0);

int[] intArr = null;  
list.fillWithRandom(intArr); // null pointer
list.print(intArr);
   }
 }



  import java.util.*;
  class List {


 private static final int NUMINTS = 10;



 private void list(int numInts) {
 List list = new List(10); 
 int[] intArr = new int[10];
 } 

public List(int i) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }


//fill array with random numbers
 public void fillWithRandom(int intArr[]) {
 Random r;
 r = new Random();

 int i;

 for(i=0; i < NUMINTS ; i++)

 intArr[i] = r.nextInt();     // null pointer
} 

 //display numbers
public void print(int intArr[]) {
int i;
for(i=0 ; i < NUMINTS; i++)
System.out.println(intArr[i]);


    }
  }
```

My message in the compiler says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at List.fillWithRandom(List.java:28)
 at Main.main(Main.java:9)

Comment: can you edit your post so that the code shows up as code, its much easier to read. Also including the line numbers wouldnt hurt.

Comment: Yes, you made `intArr = null` and then tried to use it, which earned you a `NullPointerException`.  Your comments show that you already knew that.  So what's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set your `int` array to null, then pass it to `fillWithRandom`. Then, without actually allocating any space for that array, you attempt to populate it.

You need to allocate memory before you can use it.

---

Here's a nice simple one to start with:

### test.java:

```
    public class test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            MyList list = new MyList(10);
            list.fillWithRandom();
            list.print();
        }
    }
```

### MyList.java:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class MyList {
        private int[] list = null;

        public MyList(int numInts) {
            list = new int[numInts];
        }

        public void fillWithRandom() {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
                list[i] = r.nextInt();
        }

        public void print() {
            for (int i=0 ; i < list.length; i++)
                System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eclipse is telling me to set an initial value to  int[] intArr;

Comment: That's good advice, you should listen :-) Quick fix is probably just to change (in `main`) `int[] intArr = null;` to `int[] intArr = new int[10];` although you may well have other things that need working out as well.

Comment: It works to do it that way.  But I'd prefer to setup the array in the List class.  That has been causing me the trouble basically.

Comment: I'd prefer that too, since the array is a property of the list class rather than `main`. But if that's what you want, you should probably ask for it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I had to tweak it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You passed in a null array `intArr` to method `fillWithRandom`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Main {
private static Object intArr;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List list = new List(10);
    list.fillWithRandom(intArr);
list.print(intArr);

}
  }




   import java.util.Random;
 public class List {

 private int[] list = null;

 public List(int numInts) {
 list = new int[numInts];
 }

 public void fillWithRandom(Object intArr) {
     Random r = new Random();
     for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
         list[i] = r.nextInt();

 }
 public void print(Object intArr) {
     for(int i=0; i <list.length; i++)
     System.out.println(list[i]);
 }


   }
```